# UITextField, when resigning first responder, causing strange animation scroll of text

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, interface-builder

I've got a couple of UITextFields implemented in a UITableView for a login form. When resigning first responder in both **the very first time**, a really strange animation jump is occurring. Since these are almost entirely build in Interface Builder with a .xib file, I've got virtually no code to add in. But here's a fun .gif that shows the behavior:

[image]

**Update:**

I've narrowed it down to the fact that I'm listening to keyboard events to adjust the view constraints. This is the code that's causing the problem:

```
func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    // tried self.formContainer.layoutIfNeeded() here too to force pending layouts
    formContainerYConstraint.constant = 40
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4) { () -> Void in
        self.formContainer.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

... where the form container is a view that houses the table view and login button.

Comment: how you switching control from first text field to second one

Comment: Simulator, so tab (next) and clicking as well does it.

Comment: silly  but just for confirmation?Is it a textView or TextField??

Comment: Are you reloading the cell or the table? Show what code you do have.

Comment: Rohit - yes text**field**, Wain I'll add the table view delegate code in shortly.

Comment: Narrowed down the root cause and posted the code for that.

Comment: I have the same problem. Specifically this happens when resigning first responder in the same layout loop as you call `layoutIfNeeded` in an `animateWithDuration` block.

Comment: Can be related to issue with `sizeThatFits:` and UITextView on iOS 8.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30519940

Answer (score 4):

Feels like a total hack (and I'd love for someone to post a better answer) but in the mean time, I've resolved this by adding a slight delay to the animation action - I suspect this is related to the become- and resignFirstResponder events occurring when switching between two input fields.

```
let delay: dispatch_time_t = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(0.1 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
dispatch_after(delay, dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
    self.formContainerYConstraint.constant = 40
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4) { () -> Void in
        self.formContainer.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

Comment: Was about to post the exact same question with the exact same hacky solution. I haven't been able to find anything better either.

Comment: Interestingly for me before I applied the above code the animation duration was not respected and seemed to automatically sync with the keyboard animation.  After adding dispatch_after I had to tweak the animation duration to try and match what the keyboard was doing

Comment: Yeah it's an ugly hack for sure

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
  [textField layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

Comment: as suggested here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33544054/why-is-uitextfield-animating-on-resignfirstresponder/35407734#35407734